# Python-How to do Algebraic Math with Exponents and Square Roots

Tags: python, math, algebra

so I am having issues trying to do basic math in Python. I can do basic math, but when I add in exponents, square roots, etc, I have errors with the IDE. How do I do this?

Here are a few of my problems that I am having issues with:

```
(n(n-1))/2)
(4)* pi * r ** 2=
(r(cos(a)**2) + r(sin(b))**2)**(.5)
((y**2) - (y**1))/((x**2) - (x**1))=
```

Comment: `n(n-1)` isn't proper syntax, and you have random equal signs?

Comment: You might want to try http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html

Comment: Try writing n*(n-1)

Comment: yeah so this is what I have going on right now: print(n*(n-1))/2)

Comment: `(y**1)` is an odd way to write `y`, using 6 symbols in the place of 1. Also, `print(n*(n-1))/2)` has unbalanced parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

1. `(n*(n-1))/2` should work if you have already given n a numeric value (e.g. n=2 or something). Your original expression has unbalanced parentheses (three closing parens and only two opening parens) and it is missing the multiplication sign (*) which is necessary in python, otherwise `n(n-1)` would be interpreted as the function `n` supplied with the input `n-1`, in which case you get a message like "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable", assuming you had previously defined `n=2` or the like. It's telling you that the integer n cannot be called like a function, which is how it interprets `n()`.
2. To get pi (3.14159...) in python, you should import the math package and then use math.pi like this:

   ```
   import math
   r = 2
   x = 4*math.pi*r**2
   ```

   You don't need parentheses around the 4. Parentheses are used for grouping, when you need operations to be done in a different order than the standard order of operations. You don't need the trailing equal sign (that's a syntax error).
3. In the third expression you are using implicit multiplication notation which is fine for pencil and paper but in python you need to use * every time you multiply. Also, you need to import the math package and then use math.sin and math.cos.

   ```
   import math
   a = 90
   b = 45
   x = (r*(math.cos(a)**2) + r*(math.sin(b))**2)**(.5)
   ```
4. There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the last expression except the trailing = sign which should be removed. Store the result of this expression in a variable if you want to keep it for future use:

   ```
   z = ((y**2) - (y**1))/((x**2) - (x**1))
   ```

   If you just type the expression at the command line it will print the result immediately:

   ```
   x = 3
   y = 2
   ((y**2) - (y**1))/((x**2) - (x**1))
   ```

   but if you are using this expression in a script you want to save the result in a variable so you can use it later or print it out or something:
   `z = ((y**2) - (y**1))/((x**2) - (x**1))`

   As was previously pointed out in the comments, `x**1` is the same, mathematically, as `x` so it's not clear why you would want to write it this way, but it's not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

## You can use [`math.pow()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.pow) or the simpler `**` syntax:

There are two ways to complete basic maths equations in python either:

use the `**` syntax. e.g:

```
>>> 2 ** 4
16
>>> 3 ** 3
27
```

or use `math.pow()`. e.g:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.pow(5, 2)
25.0
>>> math.pow(36, 0.5)
6.0
```

As you can see, with both of these `functions` you can use any `real` power so `negative` for `inverse` or `decimals` for `roots`.

In general, for these types of equations, you want to look into the [`math`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) module. It has lost of useful functions and defined constants that you may find useful. In particular for your specific problems: [`math.pi`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.pi) and [these trig. functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#trigonometric-functions).

I hope these examples and the links I made are useful for you :)